# Accessing a variable from constructor to actionPerformed method

Tags: java, variables, button, jframe

I have a variable ("data") that comes through into the JFrame through the constructor. I also have a button with an ActionPerformed method attached to it. I need to be able to access the variable "newData" from inside the ActionPerformed:

```
public JFrame(int data) {
    initComponents();
    
    int newData = data + 5;
}

private void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    System.out.println(newData);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: make `newData` a field rather than a local variable

Comment: Right, variables declared (like `int`, if you include the type) in a method are *local* to a method, and can't be accessed outside of it.  You need to move `int newData` to outside the method so that it's an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration (the part with the type, `int` here) outside of the method.  This makes `newData` an instance field rather than a local variable, and it is now accessible outside of the method (or in this case constructor).

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

    private int newData;

    public MyJFrame(int data) {
        initComponents();
        newData = data + 5;
    }
    
    private void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        System.out.println(newData);
    }
```